# assandra.InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid INTEGER constant (42607589003) for Identifier of type text"

Tags: python-2.7, cassandra

I am trying to run a simple query on cassandra host via python.

```
>>session.execute('SELECT * from "users" WHERE "userid"=42607589003')
```

But i get error below,"userid" is of type text, i tried different permutations by enclosing in double quotes too, but cannot figure out why this error is thrown

```
>>cassandra.InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid INTEGER constant (42607589003) for Identifier of type text"
```

can somebody let me know whats  wrong here?

Comment: Why do you need quotes around users and userid?
did you try this? 
```"SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid='abc'"```

Comment: without quotes would give me this error: cassandra.InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured columnfamily users"

Comment: can you share your table schema?

Comment: i doubt i can give the whole schema. but the userid is of 'text'

Answer (score 1):

42,607,589,003 isn't representable as a 32 bit integer. Have you tried it without quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Propably you set your variable in cassandra "userid" as text and you trying to send int 42607589003.

Change this: session.execute('SELECT * from "users" WHERE "userid"=42607589003')
To this: session.execute("SELECT * from users WHERE userid='42607589003'")